# while заглючил

Tags: php

не выводится последняя добавленная новость

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,date,author,mini_img,view,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments AS c WHERE c.post=n.id) AS count_comment FROM news AS n ORDER BY id");

    if (!$result)
    {
    echo "Запрос не прошел!";
    exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $myrow['count_comment_img'] = ($myrow['count_comment']) ? $class_comments = "comments_links" : $class_comments = "comments_links no";
    printf ("
    <table border='0' align='center' class='news'>
    <td class='news_title_head'>
    <div class='news_name'><a class='link_big' href='index_view.php?id=%s'>%s</a></div>
    <div class='post-date'>
    <p class='news_adds'>Дата добавления: %s</p>
    </div>
    <div class='head_info'>
    <p class='author_adds alignleft'>Автор: <b>%s</b> |<span style='margin-left:10px;'>%s просмотров</span></p>
    <p class='comments_all alignright'><a class='$class_comments' href='index_view.php?id=%s#comments'>%s Comments</a></p>
    </div>
    </td>
    <tr class='sub_news'>
    <td class='news_title'>
    <div class='news_img'><div id='yahoo'><img title='%s' class='news_img1' align='left' src='%s' width='150' height='140' style='/* Скругленные углы */
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius:20px;'></div></div>
    <br><div class='news_desc'>%s</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>",$myrow['id'],$myrow['title'],$myrow['date'],$myrow['author'],$myrow['view'],$myrow['id'],$myrow['count_comment'],$myrow['title'],$myrow['mini_img'], $myrow['description'],rating_bar($myrow['id'],'5','static'),$myrow['id']);
    }
```

Comment: Здесь Вы просто выбросили первую прочитанную запись. Кстати, логика с do { ... } while в предыдущем варианте совершенно ни при чем. 

Вы **не печатаете** $class_comments (ранее $class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может тут проблема?

```
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

ИМХО: первая ( из 2х ) строчка - явно лишняя...

2ТС: имхо, пересмотрите свой взгляд на культуру кодирования